# Division algorithm for complex polynomials

Tags: complex-numbers

**The Question:**

This question is not actually about the complete proof for it, just one step. However, I still feel this is an appropriate title. The question is simply to show that given a polynomial $p(z)$ of degree at least 1, there exists a polynomial $h(z)$ of degree $n-1$ such that $p(z) = (z-z_0)h(z) + p(z_0)$.

**My Attempt:**

Write
$$
p(z) = a_0 + a_1z + a_2z^2 + \cdots + a_nz^n, \\
h(z) = b_0 + b_1z + b_2z^2 + \cdots + b_{n-1}z^{n-1}.
$$
Then we have
$$
(z-z_0)h(z) = b_0z + b_1z^2 + b_2z^3 + \cdots + b_{n-1}z^n - z_0(b_0 + b_1z + b_2z^2 + \cdots + b_{n-1}z^{n-1}).
$$
By comparing coefficients we find $a_k = b_{k-1} - z_0b_k$, with $b_n = 0$. Thus we can solve for each $b_k$ by working backwards from $b_{n-1} = a_n$.

Now, however, I am a bit stuck on the $p(z_0)$ part. Using the method described above I don't really end up with anything but $p(z_0) = a_0 + z_0b_0$, and I don't seem to have used the fact that $a_n \neq 0$ anywhere. That last remark really bothers me. I feel like I should definitely be using the fact that $p(z)$ is in fact of degree $n$.

Comment: $\,b_{n-1}=a_n\,$ $\;-\;$ Then $\,a_n = 0 \implies b_{n-1}=0\,$. Similarly, $\,a_n = a_{n-1} = 0 \implies b_{n-1}=b_{n-2}=0\,$. So $\,h\,$ will always have degree $1$ less than $p$.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that if it is true for $p$ that $$p(z)=(z-z_0)q(z)-p(z_0)\tag1$$ then if $p$ is not constant, $p(z)-p(z_0)$ has the same degree as $p,$ and we get $\deg q=\deg p-1.$  (When $p(z)$ is constant, $q(z)=0.$)

So the degree of $q$ follows just from the existence of a solution to $(1).$

Then, it is easier to first prove it for the specific case $p(z)=z^k.$ $$
\begin{align} 
p(z)&=z^k\\&=(z^k-z_0^k)+z_0^k\\&=\left((z-z_0)\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}z_0^{i}z^{k-1-i}\right) +p(z_0)\tag2
\end{align} $$

Then note that if it is true for both $p_1(z)$ and $p_2(z)$ polynomials , then it is true for $p(z)=a_1p_1(z)+a_2p_2(z),$ for $a_1,a_2$ complex numbers.

Finally, prove by induction that it is true for any polynomial $p.$

---

We can use $(2)$ to get an explicit formula. If $$p(z)=\sum_{i=0}^na_iz^i$$

Then $$
\begin{align} 
p(z)-p(z_0)&=\sum_{i=1}^n a_{i}(z-z_0)\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}z_0^{i-1-j}z^j\\
&=(z-z_0)\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\left(\sum_{i=j+1}^{n}a_iz_0^{i-1-j}\right)z^j
\end{align} $$

So if $$b_j= \sum_{i=j+1}^{n}a_iz_0^{i-1-j}$$ then $$q(z)=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} b_jz^j$$
is your quotient.

When $n>0,$ $b_{n-1}=a_n,$ this also gives the degree of $q$ is one less than the degree of $p$ $\deg p>0.$

---

This works for polynomials over any commutative ring of coefficients.

General division algorithm doesn’t over arbitrary rings, but general division algorithm **does** work over fields, like the fields of complex numbers, real numbers or rational numbers.